# Google Maps API - Get data from two tables

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a question regarding the correct design for Google Engine & Google Maps.

Requirement:

1. Have a list of stores with their individual attributes (location, hours, etc.).
2. Each store can be mapped to multiple store types (outlet, retail, business, etc.).

I understand that #1 can be achieved by importing the my data into my Google Maps Engine in a table. #2 is a different set of data with Store PKID as a foreign key and another column specifying the store type. #2 does not have a PKID - i.e. 1 store FK can map to multiple store types and hence, will be represented by multiple rows in #2.

Example:

```
Table 1:
Store ID, Hours
1,5-8
2,5-5
3,5-5

Table 2:
Store ID, Type
1, Outlet
1, Retail
2, Business
3, Retail
```

Can I query the two tables in one go using Google Maps API?

OR

Do I have to first get the list of stores from table 1 and then query table 2 for each store?

What design considerations should I keep in mind?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Great example of how to ask a question here.  I have up-voted you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question for the benefit of others:

From an application perspective, the number of external calls should be as minimal as possible. There is a fine line between ideal system architecture and performance/costs of the architecture.

In the above example, it would require two calls to get the job done. In addition, the 2nd table is not being used for anything else; hence, I have decided to implement the below table structure:

```
Table 1:
Store ID, Hours, Outlet, Retail, Business
1,5-8,true,false,false
2,5-8,false,true,true
```

Now, I do realize that the data is not normalized; however, I have reduced # of external queries.